# Save HTML form data into JSON using Python

Tags: python, html, webforms, micropython

I want to store the HTML form data in variables and then convert the HTML form data to store in JSON file using python. I want to store the file locally in my device. the example form is below:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <h1 id="heading">ABC</h1>
            <div id="input_name" class="input">
              <input id="name" type="text" Placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div id="input_class" class="input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Branch" name="branch" required>
            </div>
            <div id="input_year" class="input">
              <input id="school" type="text" name="college" placeholder="College">
            </div>
            <div class="id input">
              <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I  have attached a sample code how I am using the requests and regex built-in lib for it. I am using it for one Checkbox with one password text field but how to do it for multiple fields in form (including multiple Checkbox and radio button).

```
def handle_configure(client, request):
    match = ure.search("ssid=([^&]*)&password=(.*)", request)

    if match is None:
        send_response(client, "Parameters not found", status_code=400)
        return False
    try:
        ssid = match.group(1).decode("utf-8").replace("%3F", "?").replace("%21", "!")
        password = match.group(2).decode("utf-8").replace("%3F", "?").replace("%21", "!")
    except Exception:
        ssid = match.group(1).replace("%3F", "?").replace("%21", "!")
        password = match.group(2).replace("%3F", "?").replace("%21", "!")
```

I am adding my client request response here:

```
request = b'POST /configure HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.4.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:95.0) Gecko/95.0 Firefox/95.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-IN\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 32\r\nOrigin: http://192.168.4.1\r\nDNT: 1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: http://192.168.4.1/\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n\r\nssid=HOME-WiFi&password=HomEWiFiIn'
```

I am unable to proceed forward with Python logic to save data in json file so seeking your guidance. ***I do not wish to use jquery, JavaScript or PHP for the above purpose***. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the css tag, it's not needed nor relevant

Comment: You use javascript ???

Comment: How are you getting the data? Are you submitting the form and handling the request in Python?

Comment: @Jesse Yes, I am submitting the form and handling the request in python, but how to do that I am not sure.

Comment: Can you show us how you are handling the request? Are you using a library like flask, django? The form data you need is likely in a dictionary (i.e. `request.POST` for django) and from there you can do `json.dumps(request.POST)`

Comment: No, I am not using any flask or django. i am simply using ```requests``` and ```re``` built-in libs. Eg.:  ```match = ure.search("ssid=([^&]*)&password=(.*)", request)``` where request is the client request response. Then I am using ```decode("utf-8")``` and storing it in a variable . I am doing this for one text field how to do it for multiple field i am confused.